# Sitecore Fields Help text In experience editor onhover

Tags: experience-editor

We would need to customize the behavior of the Experience Editor to display the field help text on mouse hover instead of on click. Could you please provide the solutions on this.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of field help text? Can you add a screenshot?